# How do I register a function to be called at a specific time in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, timer

How do I register code to be called at a specific time in the future?

I want to allow users to create "objects" and have a handler that automatically emails them statistics about that object after a given amount of time (say 1 hour). Ideally, I could register a handler with some part of the Symfony codebase, but I can't find out how to do this (all googling so far is stuff about the timing of Symfony2's beta :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you create a Symfony2 console command, as then you get access to the whole framework including the dependency injection container and so on.  The specifics of this are over in the [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console.html), so I won't duplicate them here as the cookbook entry is pretty thorough.  Once you've created your command class with a task name of eg `example:my-task`, you can then pop an entry in your crontab file similar to the following:

```
# Run your command every 5 mins
*/5 * * * * /path/to/symfony2/app/console example:my-task
```

appending any command-line arguments as appropriate eg `--env=prod`.  The path above is the path to wherever your Symfony2 application is and subsequently being able to run the Symfony2 `app/console` script.